# React Redux thunk: dispatching to store takes too long

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to fetch all images (userPics, etc..) and store the Base64 string in my Redux store (so that I can use them offline). Therefore I load/fetch those images at the start of the App before rendering. I use `redux-thunk`, so I can dispatch an action (fetching, returns a Promise) and then (`.then()`) dispatch to store them.

However, not all images are stored before rendering (although I'm pretty sure I declared the Promise(s) right). This is my cache (for images) reducer (incl. fetch action):

```
const initialState = {
  images: [],
}


//Reducer
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    let index, images;
    images = state.images.slice();
    index = images.findIndex(x => x.url===action.url);
    switch (action.type){
        //Store images
        case STORE_IMAGE:
            if( index === -1){
                images.push({url:action.url,  
                            img: action.img, 
                            width: action.width, 
                            height: action.height});
            }else{
                images[index] = {url:action.url, 
                                img: action.img, 
                                width: action.width, 
                                height: action.height};
            }
            return {
                ...state,
                images: images
            }

        default: 
            return state
    }
}

//ARE THERE SIDE EFFECTS?
export const storeImage = (url, img, width, height) => {
    return dispatch => 
        dispatch({
            type: STORE_IMAGE,
            url: url,
            img: img,
            width: width,
            height: height
        });

}

//Fetch, returns Promise (used to render when resolved)
export const cacheImage = (url) => {
    return dispatch => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //test if images is already fetched
        let images = store.getState().cache.images;
        let index = images.findIndex(x => x.url===url);
        if(index === -1){
            let mimeType = mime.lookup(url.split("?")[0]);
            RNFetchBlob.fetch('GET', url)
              .then((response) => {

                let base64Str = response.data;
                var imageBase64 = 'data:'+mimeType+';base64,'+base64Str;
                // Get resolution
                Image.getSize(imageBase64, (width, height) => {
                    // Store base64 image
                    dispatch(storeImage(url, imageBase64, width, height));
                    resolve(imageBase64);
                });

             }).catch((error) => {
               // error handling
               reject(error);
            });
        }else{
            //already fetched
            resolve(images[index].img);
        }
    });
}
```

If I include a `setTimeout()` for resolving the Promise (in Images.getSize) with a sufficient time, all images are stored before rendering. This makes me wonder, because I thought the inner `dispatch(storeImage)` is a function without side effects (at least it should be)?! I can't make another Promise out of that, right?

Answer (score 0):

I see no errors in your code: I expect `Image.getSize` to be the culprit. Check the implementation if there's a reason the callback is not called.

That said: I suggest you do some investigation if Base64 is the best format to store your images in local cache.

Comment: I already added a dispatch to Store the Image before getting the Dimensions (with null values for width and height) but it had no effect. The promise was resolved before all images were in store..  but thanks for your answer.. what would you suggest for storing cached/offline images?